# Cómo puedo agregar varios objetos en un ArrayList

Tags: java

```
ArrayList <Venta> ventas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ventas.add(new Venta(args...));` donde `args...` son los parametros del constructor de la clase `Ventas`